# File permission when creating a file

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have a php file that when ran, it creates another file. Should the php file that creates the file have 750 permissions to write the file or should the dir that the file is being written to have the 750 permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the permissions of the php file have **nothing** to do with that.

---

Assuming that the user who executes the script is the *owner* of the directory the permissions of that directory should be set to

```
0700
```

or

```
0750
```

if members of the group that owns the directory should already have write and listing permissions. But I cannot give you the exact permissions for your use case. Therefore I need to know what is the exact scenario

Comment: the dir I am trying to write the file to already has 755, then why isn't my file writing the file it is supposed to.

Comment: then permissions are sufficient. show your code that opens and writes the file

Comment: the code and issue is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16451497/2056707

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule of thumb in the permission. Maximum permissions are Files 0644 and Folders 0750.

If you need to give any permission simply chmod it just before the action and then change it to the above rules.

Hope it help.